# Error when I run sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates

Whenever I run `sudo apt-get update`, I get this error:

```
E: GPG error: http://opart.org ./ InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

I get the same error when I try to install something via the software center.

```
Failed to download repository information, Check your internet connection
```

And the details has the same error that I get on the terminal.

This is the output of sudo grep -R "opart.org" /etc/apt/ :

```
sudo grep -R "opart.org" /etc/apt/
/etc/apt/sources.list.save: deb opart.org/debian/ ./
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb opart.org/debian/ ./
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb opart.org/debian/ ./
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb opart.org/debian/ ./
```

I'v removed the http from the links since i cant post more than 2 links here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `grep -R "opart.org" /etc/apt/`

Comment: For which package you have used `http://opart.org` ?

Comment: I actually do not know. How do i find out. I just switched over to ubuntu yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The side http://opart.org isn't longer available.

> This web site is for sale

Therefore

```
grep -rl 'opart.org' /etc/apt/ | xargs sudo sed -i '/opart\.org/d'
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: And what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo sed -i '/opart\.org/d' /etc/sources.list
```

That will fix the issue with `sudo apt-get update`.

The problem was because you have added the software source that does not exist any more to your `/etc/sources.list` file.